# how to return registervalues in x86

Tags: c, assembly, x86

what is the correct syntax for writing an x86 assembly function that returns one register value to a calling function in C? is there some stack manipulation involved, if so how is this cleaned -up afterwards? I would be thankful for a simple example. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Study the calling conventions of your compiler.

Comment: It depends on what calling convention the rest of your code uses; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions.

Comment: @alexey. hmm, ok. I am using gcc.

Comment: What do you mean with "returns one register value"? What register? Return how? Many architectures pass function arguments and return values in cpu registers. Others don't. Also, since you're talking about registers, there is no correct syntax in C. C doesn't have a concept of registers.

Comment: @art. I ment one of the general porpouse registers, one random one or %eax if only that would be possible to return. Exactly about c and assembly. Thats why I want the assembly function to return the registervalue as a type that c can catch (for instance a long).

Comment: I'm 99% sure that this is an XY question. You ask about how to do Y, because you think that is the way to achieve X. Explain what you really want to do, and I'm sure we can help you. But as it stands, your question is quite hard to answer [although you have accepted an answer, so I guess you should really ask ANOTHER question].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, following header and footer are used for 32bit procedures:

```
MyProc:
; prologue
    push  ebp
    mov   ebp, esp

    sub   esp, sizeof_local_variables   ; this is optional, if your procedure
                                        ; needs some local variables.

; here write your code. 
; The arguments are accessible on addresses [ebp+8+some_const]
; The local variables are on addresses [ebp-some_const] 
; where some_const must be less than sizeof_local_variables of course.

; Return the result in EAX register if you want to return it to C/C++ or other HLL.

; epilogue
    mov   esp, ebp       ; restores the stack pointer as it was on the entry
    retn  n              ; returns to the caller. If you are using CCALL convention
                         ; (usualy in C code) you have to omit "n" constant.
                         ; n is the count of bytes of the pushed arguments.
                         ; in 32bit environment it must be multiply of 4
```

The sequence "push ebp/mov ebp, esp" can be provided by the instrunction "enter" and "mov esp, ebp" by "leave" but I preferred to make it more understandable and using explicit instructions is faster on most platforms.

Comment: very interesting with the cleanup afterwards. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With gcc, you can use inline assembly, and not worry about the stack too much.

```
unsigned int get_eax(void) {
    unsigned int eax;
    asm("" : "=a" (eax));
    return eax;
}
```

This uses an assembly section with no instructions in it, with an output constraint that says the value of eax should be put in a variable named `eax`.

I use `unsigned int` for the register, which isn't very portable, but inline assembly isn't very portable anyway. The variable needs to be the size of a register.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux if you return an int, return in eax, a long (in 64bit mode only) return in rax.